# C++, member address

Tags: c++, cuda, edg

I am trying to make nvcc (g++/EDG) play nicely with latest boost

```
template<typename U>                                        \
   static false_type has_member(tester<&U::member_name>*); \
```

gives

```
/opt/boost/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:65: error: ‘&’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
/opt/boost/include/boost/thread/locks.hpp:65: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: nvcc - that is - the CUDA compiler, right?

Comment: Added [cuda] tag to make it easier to be found by CUDA guys :) From my experience: I was succesful with boost 1.42 and had nvcc errors with boost 1.45

Answer (score 1):

What version of nvcc are you using?

I tried reproducing the error in the following simpler case, but it succeeded with compilation (CUDA 3.2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Test {
public:
    int x;
};

template <int Test::*S>
class Template {
};

template <typename T>
class Run {
    Template<&T::x> foo;
};

int main() {
    Run<Test> foo;
}
```